# Allow only numbers in Input in React (antd styling)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

I know type=number works but that is not what i want.
**my HTML:**

```
<FormItem style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
    {getFieldDecorator('matchPercentage', {
        initialValue: this.state.matchPercentage
     })( 
        <Input type="number" value={this.state.matchPercentage} onChange={this.handlePercentMatch} style={{ width: 100, marginLeft: 10 }} />
     )}
</FormItem>
```

**my Function:**

```
handlePercentMatch = (e) => {
    const isInteger = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if (e.target.value === '' || isInteger.test(e.target.value)) {
      this.setState({ matchPercentage: e.target.value })
    }
  }
```

My `isInteger.test()` is working meaning I am able to get only integers in `matchPercentage` in state. But the problem is It is not reflecting in GUI. I am still able to type alphabets even though they are not being set into state.

> I know type="number" works but that is not what i want. I want to validate using react as i want control decimals and upto how many digits and non negative

I have added my code here
https://codepen.io/DadyByte/pen/xYgLvy?editors=1010

> I found the root cause. If you use `FormItem` you will be allowed to type no matter what. If I use `Input` outside FormItem my code is working. What can I do to prevent it

Comment: Please share `Input` component's code.

Comment: its a huge form component @Prakashsharma. What could be the problem?

Comment: @DadyByte just make sure, inside Input component you defined `value={this.props.value}` on `input` element, if you define that it will work, otherwise it will allow user to add any value. Check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067719/how-to-allow-only-numbers-in-textbox-in-reactjs)

Comment: @DadyByte Nothing seems wrong with the above logic. I think there is something wrong with `Input ` component itself.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a `e.preventDefault()` in case the _if_ condition does not pass.

Comment: @LucaFabbri `e.preventDefault()` is not working

Comment: can you show some code from the `Input` component? I don't think you are passing value into the html `<input>` component since you are getting non-controlled behavior

Comment: If you don't want to paste all of the input component, maybe just put it in a codepen?

Comment: @EricHasselbring Input is an Antd Component. click here to know its api docs: https://ant.design/components/input/. I tried replacing Input with input still the same output.

Comment: you should use their InputNumber seems like they have a lot of already implemented features you are using

Comment: @EricHasselbring I am currently using that only but InputNumber also allows you to type alphabets and validates on `onBlur()` function. What I really Want is not allow the typing of alphabets

Comment: @MaxMillington I dont know how to add antd library support in codepen

Comment: @DadyByte Your code is working check: https://codesandbox.io/s/ly2j4nnzkz

Comment: @Prakashsharma The problem is in FormItem. Check my code in Code Pen attached in problem statement

Comment: @LucaFabbri Check my code snippet in codepen for problem in detail

Answer (score 8):

Just use the code below and it would just accept the numbers,
also it works for ant design Input component.

```js
<input
    onKeyPress={(event) => {
        if (!/[0-9]/.test(event.key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Ant Design has an InputNumber Component. You could use something like this

```
import {InputNumber} from 'antd';
```

Usage

```
<InputNumber placeholder="Age (Max Age :100,  Min Age:1)" size={'large'} min={1} max={100} onChange={this.handleAgeChange} />
```

Then your handleAgeChange Functionality could look like

```
 handleAgeChange = (value) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => (
         { ...prevState, age:value }
    ));
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest and far from complicated way according to www.w3schools.com :

```
onHandleChangeNumeric = e => {
 let valu = e.target.value;

 if (!Number(valu)) {
 return;
 }

 this.setState({ [e.target.name]: valu });
};
```

On render input :

```
 <input
   type="text"
   className="form-control"
   name="someName"
   value={this.state.someName}
   onChange={this.onHandleChangeNumeric}
    />
```

Impoertant : Do not make type="number", it won't work.

Comment: it's simple ..but once user filled out, they won't be able to delete/backspace the last number. They'll be left with single number in the field..

Comment: To fix that, replace "if (!Number(valu)) {...}" with "if (!Number(valu)&& valu.length > 0) {..}"

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use that for telephone number input.

So here is the input you can use.

```
<input
   placeholder="Telephone Number"
   onChange={ (e) => {
     const telNo = e.target.value;
     const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
     if (telNo === '' || re.test(telNo)) {
       this.setState({ telNo: e.target.value });
     }
   }
   value={ this.state.telNo }
   type="tel"
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 has a native solution:

`<input type="number">`

This is assuming your `Input` component is using the HTML5 `<input />` tag

Comment: But I can still type "-".

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's quite simple just pass **type = number** to your input field`<input value={this.state.matchPercentage} onChange={this.handlePercentMatch} 
 type="number">`

Answer (score 0):

###### Hi @DadyByte,

Set the pattern attribute to prevent the user from entering non-integer values in the input field.

```js
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" value={this.state.matchPercentage} onChange={this.handlePercentMatch} style={{ width: 100, marginLeft: 10 }} />
```

The expression `\d*` matches any number of digits (0 or more). This will allow only integer values to be entered into the input field.

Alternatively, you could also use `/^[0-9]+$/`.

```js
handlePercentMatch = (e) => {
  const isInteger = /^[0-9]+$/;
  if (e.target.value === '' || isInteger.test(e.target.value)) {
    this.setState({ matchPercentage: e.target.value }, () => {
      e.target.setSelectionRange(e.target.value.length, e.target.value.length);
    });
  }
}
```