# How to enter any budget value?

Tags: python, django

I set my Django model field `budget` but when I try the following...

```
budget = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

...only non-numeric characters can be entered (like

> abc,#

etc...

This should work. 
- I can key in digits in other programs on my computer, but not in my web form `budget` field. 
- I tried other fields like: `models.IntegerField()` or `models.PositiveIntegerField()`
- I ran `npm run dev`, `python manage.py makemigrations`, `migrate`, `runserver`.
Same thing. Digit keys frozen.

Any other ideas? Thanks.

======= UPDATE

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    shopping_list = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    budget = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="leads", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

======= UPDATE

I tried the code in my REACT frontend web form by Iqbal Hussain... I still get the same. Only characters are accepted in the `DecimalField`.
I thought that was a Django backend issue...It could be a REACT-related issue.

======= UPDATE

The inspector shows:

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="integer" value="">
```

The React code for the budget input is:

```
...
<div className="form-group">
    <label>Budget</label>
    <input
        className="form-control"
        type="number"
        name="integer"
        onChange={this.onChange}
        value={budget}
    />
</div>
...
```

Comment: Can you share the model form that you're having issues with? Maybe the full model might help too

Comment: @Iain. Uploaded model just now. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the form? Text is preferable to images

Comment: @Iain Shelvington, done.

Comment: Where's the form that you are having issues with?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington, posted.

Comment: Can you right-click and "inspect" the budget input and add the resulting html element to the question? Also, can you share the react code for the budget input?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington, here is the code.

Comment: Does `this.onChange` perform any validation?

Comment: `onChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]:e.target.value });` # This only says that we can input the data we enter.

Comment: `value={budget}` this comes from the state? You've given the budget input the name  "integer"

Comment: Nice observation...Now I can enter numbers and letters. I'm getting there.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code. its seems to be ok.

Please use this code to input values from backend(admin panel)
 in models.py

```
class Ordercheck(models.Model):
      budget = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

in admin.py:

```
from .models import Ordercheck

admin.site.register(Ordercheck)
```

Now create a new entry for budget field. its working here

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Iain Shelvington put me on the right track. He spotted a React issue instead of a Django issue. Then I fixed my issue with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57954369/11301109. Perfect!