# how to avoid 'e'(notation) typing for input type number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Now, I'm using the redux-form to validate the form. AND I have input type number that need to **enter just number (0-9)** by range is 1-100 **not allowed 'e'**. I would like user can enter the values from keyboard or by click.

when I enter 'e', it would be show in UI but values in redux-state is " " (blank)

***My question is how am I avoid 'e' typo from this case?***

my code

```
          <Field 
            name="weight" 
            type="number"
            component={NumberField} 
            label="Weight(%)" 
            width={250}
           />
```

Thank you

Comment: please add code related to this

Comment: @ppppp you can use regex to avoid that, check this answer [allow only numbers in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067719/how-to-allow-only-numbers-in-textbox-in-reactjs)

Comment: @MayankShukla I try to use regex to avoid but redux-form ignore 'e' letter to be ' '. So, can't use regex to validate it.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN added code

Comment: @ppppp have u tried field level validation https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN Yes, I tried and not work. Thank you :)