# How to allow only numbers on an input in react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067719/how-to-allow-only-numbers-in-textbox-in-reactjs) I came up with this code but did not work. What am I missing?

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  function onChange(e) {
    const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
    if (e.target.value === "" || re.test(e.target.value)) {
      setValue(e.target.value);
    }
  }

  return <input value={value} onChange={onChange} />;
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: You can add type="number" attribute in the input element

Comment: Well depends on what you mean by number ? integet ? decimal ?

Comment: @YashJoshi type number will add arrows on chrome + will allow typing E character and multiple dots

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI Integer

Answer (score 2):

Here's the updated answer according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687964/only-numbers-input-number-in-react/43688362)

You can use the attributes `type="number"` and `pattern="^-?[0-9]\d*\.?\d*$"`, so modify your input element like this:

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Firefox */

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" pattern="^-?[0-9]\d*\.?\d*$" />
```

source: [w3shools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp)

P.S. Or you can skip the `type=number` part and the additional CSS and just use the pattern.

Comment: even with `min="0" step="1"` I can still type stuff like plus sign, letter e, dots...

Comment: @eduardopreuss I meant to use them combined with `type=number`. Anyway, I have updated my answer after a quick search, please check above.

Comment: @eduardopreuss It may be late for answering this, but in your particular case, you can use `validity.valid` to check whether the input value is in defined range or not. You can use it like `oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"`.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use `type="number"` just like the answers above.

Or you could use a `pattern` and just enhance you implementation a bit:

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  function onChange(e) {
    if (!e.target.validity.patternMismatch) {
      setValue(e.target.value);
    }
  }

  return <input value={value || ''} pattern="^[0-9]*$" onChange={onChange} />;
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This. this worked for me. You should add the attribute pattern and in the onChange you should check the condition.

```
  const[data, setName] = useState({
    phone:""
  });


function setValue(e){
  if(e.target.validity.valid){
    setName({...data,phone:e.target.value});
  }
  
}

  return (
    <form>
      <label>Numbers Only</label>
      <input name="phone" type ="text" pattern="[0-9]*" value={data.phone} onChange={setValue} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form> 
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to convert whatever is written to its numerical characters only. You can convert the value when you use it as a parameter for the **setValue** call.

```
function onChange(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value.split(/\D/).join(''))
}
```

This will remove all non-numerical characters from user string and prevent user from changing the state. It also works well with copy-paste values since it removes all non-numerical character occurences.