# ReactJS: Allow only numbers in input in stateless non component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry, this question is maybe duplicated and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067719/how-to-allow-only-numbers-in-textbox-in-reactjs), but do not solve my problem.

I want to allow only numbers in my input outside return and in the nonstate component and inside props.

> My code.js

```
const General = props => (
    <Row>
        <Col>
            <Form.Item>
                <Input />
            </Form.Item>
        </Col>
    </Row>
)

export default General
```

Comment: How is this question different from the one you linked?

Comment: Setting it as `type="number"` should already limit the option to input anything else. You also have the `pattern` attribute which accepts a regex in the form of a string and tests that pattern on submission. You can also DIY this in a dedicated `onChange` function.

Comment: @TobiasS. question is the same but does not have my answer. I want to implement that in props.

Comment: thanks @tomleb it worked can we also limit input characters like max 10

Comment: Yes, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this please.

State is here.

```
  const [obj, setobj] = useState({ number: 0 });
```

onChange function is here.

```
  const onChangeData = (event, type, value) => {
    let data = null;
    data = value;
    setobj({ ...obj, [type]: data })
  }
```

Pure input is here.

```
<input 
   type="number" 
   value={obj.number}  
   onChange={(event) => props.onChangeData("number",event.target.value)} />
```

Comment: onChange is not defined

Comment: I edit for onchange acording to react

Comment: we can not call useState for props in top-level it says

Comment: I edit for props.onChangeData ? can you try ?

Comment: You think that your usestate and onchange at same component and another component. you are sending your functıon to Input component.

Comment: wait i will send you codepen

Comment: Here is my code [link](https://codepen.io/soundxpand/pen/oNprELG)

Comment: You can use pure <input .... />  instead of  import { Input, } from 'antd';